# to find the url of each page in gwt

Tags: html, url, gwt

How to find the url of the page when going from one page to the another? as in the first page we are having the url which we get by Window.location.href(),but how to get the url of the second loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is a single page application. Once you enter any other url, all your gwt states is will be cleared, and you will be no longer in your application. Hence you cannot track the url.

Answer (score 0):

GWT applications are normally *single page application* running JavaScript and do not contains lot of pages thus browser do not keep track of user interaction with Application. To use browser's history functionality, application should generate a unique URL fragment for each navigable page.

GWT provides [History Mechanism](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) to handle this situation.

Find some tutorials below about GWT History Mechanism:

- [Tutoiral 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_history_class.htm)
- [Tutorial 2](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Tutorials~History_Support)